# Is it possible to return null from List<DateTime>?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have an Interface and Class

Interface

```
List<DateTime> GetDates();
```

Class that implements the above Interface

```
public  List<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> MyDates = GetAllMyDates();
    IEnumerable<DateTime> ModifiedDates = null
    if (MyDates != null && MyDates.Count() > 0)
    {
        AllDates = MyDates.Where(....Some filter)
    }
    return AllDates.ToList();
}
```

Added a ? to the Interface but got the error

*The type 'List' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'*

Searched on that error but couldnt figure out what ive done wrong or if its not possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just return null.

Comment: The `List<T>` is a reference type. Why not just return `null`?

Comment: One thing is a type (DateTime in this case, not nullable by default) and a different story is a collection (List in this case; it refers to a given type, but has some common rules for all the types). You can return a null list if you wish.

Comment: Please include the code that actually caused the error.

Comment: It might be better to return an empty List anyway.

Comment: @Dmitry - i would have accepted your answer but its been deleted?

Comment: @Computer I've undeleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `List<T>` is a reference type you can just return `null`:

```
public List<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> MyDates = GetAllMyDates();
    IEnumerable<DateTime> ModifiedDates = null;

    if (MyDates != null && MyDates.Count() > 0)
    {
        AllDates = MyDates.Where(....Some filter)
        return AllDates.ToList();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can do this but it is almost **always** better to return an empty list. Then the users of this method won't hate you.